# select random PNG or JPEG files - python

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to write a program that picks a random photo, and i built this code:

```
random_image_path = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))])
print(random_image_path)
```

but after I started the program it sometimes prints ".ini" files...
what should I do if I want only .png or .jpeg files?
thanks!

Comment: Remove all non-JPEG and PNG files from that folder and the problem should disappear.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _but after I started the program it sometimes prints ".ini" files..._ Why do you think that is? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a filter to only include files with those extensions:

```
x for x in ... if x[-4:].lower() in ('.jpg', '.png')
```